# UVC wants to give you a Helping Hand in Solving these Unique Set of Pan digital Fractional-Decimal Relations

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

Use pure logic and deductive reasoning only. Document detailed steps in arriving at final solution.

You can use calculator minimally.

$ Given$:

Utilizing These two unique set of Pan digital fractional relations, solve for all the digits. You can try solving first without helping hand from this U V C equation

U, V, C are 3 distinct digits..values can vary from 1 to 9.

CU is a concatenated number

$U^V  x  V^U$   = $CU$

$Unique $Set of $Pan digital $ $fractional $ and $Decimal Relationships:$

All the letters represent distinct digits(1 to 9).

All the words in both equations on either side represent concatenated Numbers

$BUGLOV$  /  $ACE$  =  $UBE$.$LOGVCA$

$OLAGEVB$ /  $CU$    =  $BUGVEL$.$OCA$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $U = 2$ $V = 3$ $C=7$
>  Reasoning
>  $u^v \times v^u = cu$ means that the multiplication must result in a 2 digit number.
>  This means u and v are small digits and there are not so many cases. We can try them out.
>  None of them can be 1 as the result it would be a 1 digit number.
>  u=2, v=3 results in 8x9 = 72. Good
>  u=2, v=4 results in 16x16>100. Stop incrementing v
>  u=3, v=2 results in 9x8 = 72. Not good.
>  Rest of the cases go over 100.

From the second division:

> I actually  transformed it into a multiplication and concluded that a can be 0 or 5 otherwise we don't get a n integer from . But A cannot be 0 since the first division contains one factor that starts with A. SO A=5.

Further:

> From the same second division, then decimals are now o75.  This, multiplied by 72 must be divisible with 1000 in order to get an integer. The only possible values for o are 3 and 8, but 3 is already taken. So o=8.  
>  From the same equation I got that b=1 since a six digit number (ignore decimals) multiplied by 72 we get a 7 digit number. if b>=2 we get an 8 digit number.  
>  Taking decimals again we get 875*72 = 63000. This means that 2*L+3 = 1 (mod 10). So 2*l = 8 (mod 10).  So L can be 9 or 4.
>  but bugvel.oca = 12g3el.875 > 120000. And 120000*72 = 864000 so  > 864000. So L>6. So L=9.

Now we are left with...

> 2 letters g,e and 2 digits. 4,6. We could probably calculate them but there are only 2 combinations. So let's do the math.
>  g=4, e = 6: 124369,875×72 = 8954631. Valid.
>  g=6 e=4: 126349,875×72 = 9097191. Not valid.

Now we got all:

> B=1, U=2, V=3, G=4, A=5, E=6, C=7, O=8, L=9.

Comment: Excellent deductive quick work...would you be able to solve it without Uvc relation?

Comment: Not sure. I didn't even tiuch one of the divisions. I didnt even check it because i am lazy. Maybe, maybe not